# How do I launch an amazon ec2 spot instance with UserData?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can launch an ec2 instance without user data:

> aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price .01 --instance-count 1 --launch-specification '{ "ImageId": "ami-3275ee5b", "KeyName": "key", "InstanceType": "t1.micro"}'

But when I try it with userdata I get the following error:

> aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price .01 --instance-count 1 --launch-specification '{ "ImageId": "ami-3275ee5b", "KeyName": "key", "UserData": {"Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["#!/bin/bash\n","touch /tmp/userdata_sucess\n"]]}}, "InstanceType": "t1.micro"}'
>
> Invalid value ('OrderedDict([(u'Fn::Base64', OrderedDict([(u'Fn::Join', [u'', [u'#!/bin/bash\n', u'touch /tmp/userdata_sucess\n']])]))])') for param string:UserData of type string

I was following the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412231/how-do-i-pass-userdata-to-a-beanstalk-instance-with-cloudformation)

Answer (score 6):

When you request spot instance, Amazon require userdatа to be in base64 format.
Example:

```
aws ec2 request-spot-instances \
--spot-price 0.01 \
--instance-count 2 \
--launch-specification \
    "{ \
        \"ImageId\":\"ami-a6926dce\", \
        \"InstanceType\":\"m3.medium\", \
        \"KeyName\":\"test-key\", \
        \"SecurityGroups\": [\"test-sg\"], \
        \"UserData\":\"`base64 userdata.sh`\" \
    }"
```

More info at: [Request spot instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-instances.html)

Example is from: [Small Tip: How to use AWS CLI to start Spot instances with UserData](http://blog.xi-group.com/2014/07/small-tip-how-to-use-aws-cli-to-start-spot-instances-with-userdata/)

Answer (score 1):

Dimitrov's would have worked like this with the newline wrapping args `-w 0` added into the JSON since then there is no newline in the userdata embedded value.

```
aws ec2 request-spot-instances \
--spot-price 0.01 \
--instance-count 2 \
--launch-specification \
    "{ \
        \"ImageId\":\"ami-a6926dce\", \
        \"InstanceType\":\"m3.medium\", \
        \"KeyName\":\"test-key\", \
        \"SecurityGroups\": [\"test-sg\"], \
        \"UserData\":\"`base64 -w 0 userdata.sh`\" \
    }"
```

Comment: How do I modify EBS volume size (in integer)?

Answer (score 0):

For me only the following command worked, but not the proposed by Dimitrov:

```
user="$(cat /scripts/userdata.sh | base64 -w 0)"

aws ec2 request-spot-instances \"UserData\": \"$user\",\"InstanceType\": \"m1.small\"}"
```